# Parse deeply nested JSON file

Tags: python, json, pandas, normalize

I'm struggling to get the information I need with json_normalize.  I've looked at the documentation and probably 10 examples of deeply nested JSON files, but I can't quite grasp the context of the function well enough to extract the right info. I'm trying to build a data frame that would contain the timestamped values (values key) for each sensor.  1534023900 is the timestamp in UTC Seconds.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyueT.png)

A short sample of the JSON is below.

Any thoughts?

```js
{
    "created": "2020-05-12T15:10:37Z",
    "device": {
        "device_info": {
            "device_fw": 204,
            "device_sn": "06-02133",
            "device_trait": 2,
            "device_type": 190
        },
        "timeseries": [
            {
                "configuration": {
                    "sensors": [
                        {
                            "measurements": [
                                "BATTERY",
                                "BATTERY_MV"
                            ],
                            "port": 7,
                            "sensor_bonus_value": "Unavailable",
                            "sensor_firmware_ver": "Unavailable",
                            "sensor_number": 133,
                            "sensor_sn": "Unavailable"
                        },
                        {
                            "measurements": [
                                "REFERENCE_KPA",
                                "TEMPC_LOGGER"
                            ],
                            "port": 8,
                            "sensor_bonus_value": "Unavailable",
                            "sensor_firmware_ver": "Unavailable",
                            "sensor_number": 134,
                            "sensor_sn": "Unavailable"
                        }
                    ],
                    "valid_since": "2018-08-11T21:45:00Z",
                    "values": [
                        [
                            1534023900,
                            0,
                            19,
                            [
                                {
                                    "description": "Battery Percent",
                                    "error": false,
                                    "units": "%",
                                    "value": 100
                                },
                                {
                                    "description": "Battery Voltage",
                                    "error": false,
                                    "units": " mV",
                                    "value": 7864
                                }
                            ],
                            [
                                {
                                    "description": "Reference Pressure",
                                    "error": false,
                                    "units": " kPa",
                                    "value": 100.62
                                },
                                {
                                    "description": "Logger Temperature",
                                    "error": false,
                                    "units": " \u00b0C",
                                    "value": 28.34
                                }
                            ]
                        ]
     }
    }
   }
  }
 } 
}
```

Comment: your json is not valid can you validate it using https://jsonlint.com/ and repost it please?

Comment: My apologies. The valid JSON is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jmespath](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html) can help with nested data : the [docs](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py) are quite robust, but the basics for accessing data are : if it is a key, then you can use a `.` if it is not the first entry in the data, if it is an array/list use the `[]`

Summary of your data position : `device -> timeseries(dict)->[](array)->configuration(dict)->values(key)->[](array)->[0](array and get the first value)`

Actual code:

```
import jmespath
expression = jmespath.compile('device.timeseries[].configuration.values[][0]')
expression.search(data)
[1534023900]
```

Answer (score 0):

Revised JSON

```
{
    "created": "2020-05-12T15:10:37Z",
    "device": {
        "device_info": {
            "device_fw": 204,
            "device_sn": "06-02133",
            "device_trait": 2,
            "device_type": 190
        },
        "timeseries": [
            {
                "configuration": {
                    "sensors": [
                        {
                            "measurements": [
                                "BATTERY",
                                "BATTERY_MV"
                            ],
                            "port": 7,
                            "sensor_bonus_value": "Unavailable",
                            "sensor_firmware_ver": "Unavailable",
                            "sensor_number": 133,
                            "sensor_sn": "Unavailable"
                        },
                        {
                            "measurements": [
                                "REFERENCE_KPA",
                                "TEMPC_LOGGER"
                            ],
                            "port": 8,
                            "sensor_bonus_value": "Unavailable",
                            "sensor_firmware_ver": "Unavailable",
                            "sensor_number": 134,
                            "sensor_sn": "Unavailable"
                        }
                    ],
                    "valid_since": "2018-08-11T21:45:00Z",
                    "values": [
                        [
                            1534023900,
                            0,
                            19,
                            [
                                {
                                    "description": "Battery Percent",
                                    "error": false,
                                    "units": "%",
                                    "value": 100
                                },
                                {
                                    "description": "Battery Voltage",
                                    "error": false,
                                    "units": " mV",
                                    "value": 7864
                                }
                            ],
                            [
                                {
                                    "description": "Reference Pressure",
                                    "error": false,
                                    "units": " kPa",
                                    "value": 100.62
                                },
                                {
                                    "description": "Logger Temperature",
                                    "error": false,
                                    "units": " \u00b0C",
                                    "value": 28.34
                                }
                            ]
                        ]
                            ]
                    }
                }]
            }
}
```

Comment: 'df=pd.json_normalize(readings_json['device']['timeseries'][1]['configuration']['sensors'][1])' gets me down to the sensor level, but the values are in '[[values]]' notation and I can't figure out how to get to them

Comment: If this is a correction to your question post, it should be an edit to that post replacing the old code, not an answer post. Also clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on a similar problem where json_normalize didn't help me much. However, I have written the following piece of code that is working fine for most of the nested JSON usecases. I am still in a developing state and testing various json files.
Anyone, please feel free to comment or provide any suggestions to improve this part.

My main goal is to preserve the structure of JSON and provide it in a data frame.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def flatten_outer (data):
full_list = []
def flatten_inner(sub_data,first_level_key='',index=0,tot_len=0):
    for k,v in sub_data.items():
        full_key = first_level_key+'.'+k if first_level_key !='' else k
        if isinstance(v, dict): 
            flatten_inner(v, full_key)
            
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            
            for i in range(0, len(v)): 

                if (isinstance(v[i], dict)):
                    
                    flatten_inner(v[i], full_key,index=i, tot_len=len(v))
                else: 
                    val_ls = value_list[full_key] if full_key in value_list.keys() else []
                    val_ls.append(v)
                    value_list[full_key] = val_ls
                    break
        else:

            if full_key in value_list.keys():
                placeholder_list = value_list[full_key]
                placeholder_list[index] = v
                value_list[full_key] = placeholder_list
            else:
                if index == 0:
                    if tot_len == 0:
                        value_list[full_key] = v
                    else:
                        placeholder_list = [None]*tot_len
                        placeholder_list[0] = v
                        value_list[full_key] = placeholder_list
                else:
                    
                    dif = tot_len - index - 1
                    placeholder_list = [None] * index
                    placeholder_list.append(v)
                    placeholder_list = placeholder_list + [None] * dif
                    value_list[full_key] = placeholder_list
            
    return value_list
    
for row in data:
    value_list = dict() #creating a value_list to store key value pairs(column values) for each record
    cv =  flatten_inner(row)
    full_list.append(cv)

return full_list

def df_create_clean(full_list):
    df = pd.DataFrame(full_list)
    df = df.where(pd.notnull(df),None)
    cols = df.columns
    for col in cols:
        df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: None if (isinstance(x,list) and len(x)==0) else x)
        df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x[0] if (isinstance(x,list) and len(x)==1) else x)
    return df


def flatten_json(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(flatten_outer(data))
    cleaned_df = df_create_clean(df)
    return cleaned_df
```

Save this above code into a file **flatten_json.py**. Run the following code.

```
import flatten_json as fj
data = [{
"created": "2020-05-12T15:10:37Z",
"device": {
    "device_info": {
        "device_fw": 204,
        "device_sn": "06-02133",
        "device_trait": 2,
        "device_type": 190
    },
    "timeseries": [
        {
            "configuration": {
                "sensors": [
                    {
                        "measurements": [
                            "BATTERY",
                            "BATTERY_MV"
                        ],
                        "port": 7,
                        "sensor_bonus_value": "Unavailable",
                        "sensor_firmware_ver": "Unavailable",
                        "sensor_number": 133,
                        "sensor_sn": "Unavailable"
                    },
                    {
                        "measurements": [
                            "REFERENCE_KPA",
                            "TEMPC_LOGGER"
                        ],
                        "port": 8,
                        "sensor_bonus_value": "Unavailable",
                        "sensor_firmware_ver": "Unavailable",
                        "sensor_number": 134,
                        "sensor_sn": "Unavailable"
                    }
                ],
                "valid_since": "2018-08-11T21:45:00Z",
                "values": [
                    [
                        1534023900,
                        0,
                        19,
                        [
                            {
                                "description": "Battery Percent",
                                "error": False,
                                "units": "%",
                                "value": 100
                            },
                            {
                                "description": "Battery Voltage",
                                "error": False,
                                "units": " mV",
                                "value": 7864
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                "description": "Reference Pressure",
                                "error": False,
                                "units": " kPa",
                                "value": 100.62
                            },
                            {
                                "description": "Logger Temperature",
                                "error": False,
                                "units": " \u00b0C",
                                "value": 28.34
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                        ]
                }
            }]
        }
}   ]

df = fj.flatten_json(data)

print(df.loc[0])
```

Output

```
created                                                                                     2020-05-12T15:10:37Z
device.device_info.device_fw                                                                                 204
device.device_info.device_sn                                                                            06-02133
device.device_info.device_trait                                                                                2
device.device_info.device_type                                                                               190
device.timeseries.configuration.sensors.measurements           [[BATTERY, BATTERY_MV], [REFERENCE_KPA, TEMPC_LOG...
device.timeseries.configuration.sensors.port                                                              [7, 8]
device.timeseries.configuration.sensors.sensor_bonus_value                            [Unavailable, Unavailable]
device.timeseries.configuration.sensors.sensor_firmware_ver                           [Unavailable, Unavailable]
device.timeseries.configuration.sensors.sensor_number                                                 [133, 134]
device.timeseries.configuration.sensors.sensor_sn                                     [Unavailable, Unavailable]
device.timeseries.configuration.valid_since                                                 2018-08-11T21:45:00Z
device.timeseries.configuration.values                         [1534023900, 0, 19, [{'description': 'Battery ...
```

Now from this **df** you can take **device.timeseries.configuration.values** column to do further analysis on each sensor data.

Comment: I like the idea of the flatten json but cannot make it work - this is because, when I save using Jupyter, it doesn't save it as a module so I cannot import it. What did you do to get it to save correctly? Thanks

Comment: @MattLightbourn  thank you!
I usually follow the below method to import it as a module. Save the code as a .py file in the same folder or subfolder within which you create a Jupyter notebook and just write an import statement. You can view my GitHub repo here(https://github.com/SrikarManthatti/flatten_json_specific)
The other two ways are, just embedding the code into your Jupyter notebook cell by copy-paste
Or by using setuptools python package, creating a .whl file and pip installing it.
Let me know if this helps or not.